# Autohotkey Strike through text and change color on button press

Tags: autohotkey

how do i change the color of a text on gui and strike it through after i pressed a key (e.g. strike through and change color of "Test" to green after pressing F2)?

```
Gui Add, Text, cBlue, Test
Gui Add, Text, cRed, Press F2 to activate
Gui, Show, w350 h100

~F2:: ;now what?
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the help documentation for adjusting the font with [GuiControl](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm#Font). Additionally, [Gui , Font](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Font) shows the various options that can be adjusted.

I added a variable ("vTest") to identify the text control so that it can be manipulated by `GuiControl`.

```
f1::
Gui , Add , Text , cBlue vvTest , Test
Gui , Add , Text , cRed , Press F2 to activate
Gui , Show , w350 h100
Return

f2::
Gui , Font , cGreen strike
GuiControl , Font , vTest
Return
```